# Set<> is giving different objects for same value

Tags: java, android

Hi i am trying to implement a SQLite based Application and have some values in the table of my database. one of my column contains some similar values and to overcome the duplication , I used set<>

```
public Set<NewTableAnswers> newtableAnswers(String product_id) {
    Set<NewTableAnswers> d = new HashSet<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String SelectA1 = "SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_ANSWERS+ " WHERE " + ANSWER_ID + " = '"+ product_id + "' ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SelectA1,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            d.add(new NewTableAnswers(cursor.getString(1)));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return d;
```

if there is a duplicate, set should follow its property to avoid duplicates, but its giving me same value with different objects..like this...

[image: Different objects for same value]

**Update:**

this is my model class..

```
public class NewTableAnswers {

String pro_id;

public NewTableAnswers(String pro_id) {
    this.pro_id = pro_id;
}

public String getPro_id() {
    return pro_id;
}

public void setPro_id(String pro_id) {
    this.pro_id = pro_id;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof NewTableAnswers)) return false;
    NewTableAnswers that = (NewTableAnswers) o;
    return Objects.equals(getPro_id(), that.getPro_id());
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(getPro_id());
}
```

}

[Image of the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNHl4.png)

Comment: Did you override equals and hashCode?

Comment: for that you have to implement equals and hashcode properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the implementation of `NewTableAnswers`, in particular (as @Eran said) `equals` and `hashCode`. Read the `Set` documentation for why.

Comment: FYI: Eran and Blackbelt mean that you should implement those methods in class `NewTableAnswers`

Comment: My newTableAnswers class has just one string variable with a constructor and its getter,setter

Comment: That is not relevant, override equals and hashCode, or just use a Set of Strings

Comment: Provide a [mcve] not using the DB but a list of `String` to show the problem. This could be a simple trail of space messing with you. _PS: please check what is a SQL Injection. This is not a safe code._

Answer (score 1):

I have tried you code and it seems to work fine, if you remove the annotations.

My guess is that because of the annotations:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
```

the methods `equals` and `hashCode` are not being injected. I strongly suggest to remove these annotations, because `equals` and `hashCode` are by no means exclusive part of the API of Kitkat. They have been around since the very beginning of Java.

Comment: but now i am getting only one item in the set. so the size is always 1. i have other elements too..

Comment: @rituparna good. So removing the annotation solved one problem. If you are getting one element, even though you have multiple answers - this means that you have not defined the key properly in your code. You have now to ask yourself: which are the fields out of which the key is composed? Then you need to include these fields in your `NewTableAnswers` class and then change accordingly the `hashCode` and `equals` method to include these key fields.

Comment: @rituparna so if the image has a name and belongs to the key (*key* is what allows you to identify an object) then include the image name in the key and `hashCode` and `equals` method. This will hopefully then give you the right results.

Comment: if you see in code, i have used ANSWER_ID in my database query. this answer id is the proid.  like private static final String ANSWER_ID = "proid";   . now i have an argument passing in the whole method. this argument is passing the parameters from a loop running for an arraylist..duh!! i am bad at explaination...sorry